# $\models$ vice-versa as semantically equivalent

Tags: math-mode, symbols, relation-symbols

How to get the `$\models$`-symbol vice-versa to form a symbol for semantically equivalent like the following: `=||=`

Comment: I'm not sure what's being asked here. Can you provide a little more?

Comment: this symbol is now in unicode as Ux27DA and will ultimately be included in unicode-compliant math fonts with (presumably) the command name `\DashVDash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\models` in the standard fonts is a made up symbol

```
\DeclareRobustCommand
  \models{\mathrel{|}\joinrel\Relbar}
```

So you could do a matching combination:

```
\documentclass{article}


%\DeclareRobustCommand
%  \models{\mathrel{|}\joinrel\Relbar}
\DeclareRobustCommand
  \sledommodels{\Relbar\joinrel\mathrel{\|}\joinrel\Relbar}

\begin{document}

\[A \models B\]
\[A \sledommodels B\]

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Any particular reason for preferring `\mathrel{\|}` over `\parallel`, which is already mathrel?

Comment: @dubiousjim not really (at least not from me;-) I just copied the definition of `\models` and reflected it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a LaTeX-only environment (for example, MathJax), consider this:

```
\newcommand{\rmodels}{\ensuremath{\mathrel{=\!\!\!|}}}
```

Semantic equivalence can, for example, look like this:

```
\newcommand{\semeq}{\ensuremath\mathrel{\rmodels\!\models}}}
```

The result (pdflatex):

[image]

Depending on your context of conventions, `\models\rmodels` might be what you want:

[image]